# No Provision Profile in Adhoc

Tags: xcode

When I made Archive for my project,I met the following error.

"No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.
No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Spinns”) were found.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center."??
Is I needed real device to get Beta Testing iOS App?

Comment: voting down is discouraging ... we should educate how to search questions about their problems. Novice/new developers ask such questions rather searching over forums or documentations. Sometimes they don't even know how to search, we should guide/educate them.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your device is registered as device for test in the provisioning profiles portal or check if your device is enabled for development using xcode.
Try to check also in your build setting of your project if is specified the correct profile for debug and release version: click on your project in xCode, select the Target and go in Build Settings. Look at Code Signing and check the correct code signig identity for debug and release